# how can I filter android intent based on what number has been dialed

Tags: android, android-intent, pattern-matching, android-activity, intentfilter

I like to my application show in chooser only if certain numbers dialed.
e.g if *88*xxxx user can select my application otherwise don't show my application in chooser.

Comment: There is no such intent filter.